# How to introduce myself in linkedin?

Tags: social-media

Long before, I registered my account on LinkedIn, when pursuing BS Electrical Engineering at a university. After being graduate, I decided to change my university for getting Masters degree in a field, but the former degree still remains and appears as current. I want to ascribe the "former" or "graduate" to it but the LinkedIn choices are limited, such as:

1. student
2. student intern
3. intern student
4. student assistant
5. graduate student
6. doctoral student
7. student staff
8. Student Representative
9. Masters Student
10. student teacher
11. Student Services Specialist
12. student researcher
13. Student Coordinator
14. nursing student
15. Medical Student
16. work student
17. student work
18. PHD student
19. Student Consultant
20. Engineering Student

I would appreciate if you take a full review of all of these options mentioned above, and guide me...

Comment: Please, identify the subjects you have studied in BS and MSc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Well, your question still looks unclear.**

Let's do the job in this way:

For instance, if you have done BS and MSc in Mathematics, then you are called either of the following choices; it probably may work:

1. MSc graduate
2. MSc holder

Don't select the option, BS holder, as it is former. It will be better, if you emphasise on current degree that is MSc.

Or, if your Masters degree is continuing [not yet completed], then don't select the options of MSc, but of BSc.

Comment: This question doesn’t belong on this site. Instead of answering it, recommend it’s migration